# string.split(\\s+) unable to deal with leading spaces

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I am trying to parse this file to get two components per line:

```
10000      0
    0  10000
 3000   7000
 7000   3000
20000  21000
 3000   4000
14000  15000
 6000   7000
```

The code I am using to scan and split the contents is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] coordinates = st.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println("coordinate[0]= " + coordinates[0] + "coordinate[1]= "+ coordinates[1]);
        }
```

I am not getting the expected result for the second line "    0  10000", I am getting:

```
coordinate[0]= coordinate[1]= 0
```

Can someone please help me fix this so I get coordinate[0]= 0, coordinate[1]= 10000. All results on the internet only talk about the split(\s+) function but I couldn't find anything that solved the problem I am facing.

Even the third line is getting incorrect results (it has one space in the beginning).

```
coordinate[0]= coordinate[1]= 3000
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: it's impossible to have the same value for the zero and the first index of the output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to trim the whole string before splitting it.

```
String[] coordinates = st.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your inputs

your first line works fine as there are no empty spaces in beginning of Line.

But in case of 2nd or 3rd line there exist empty spaces.

So when you call

```
st.split("\\s+");
```

index 0 will have empty spaces, index 1 will have the value ie 0 in 2nd line

To resolve this you can trim out empty spaces before splitting something like this

```
String[] coordinates = st.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cnfikV/1) as well, to solve this

```
(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

Code would look like:

```
//read file into a string
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)), "UTF-8");

//create regex and pattern
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

//output results
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("coordinate[0]= " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("coordinate[1]= " + matcher.group(2));
}
```